# How do I  prevent .xsession-errors from eating disk space?

Tags: 11.04, xorg

Is there any way to completely disable the .xsession-errors file?  I have it as a symlink to /tmp so that my laptop hard disk can (hopefully) go to sleep for once, but at least 95% of the stuff in the file (it fills up at about 500k an hour) is...

```
(nautilus:1618): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed
```

which is total garbage to me.  I have tried doing a symlink to /dev/null but that does not work (the resulting link is overwritten), and I also do not want the activity so that hopefully my laptop can go to sleep for once.

I am using Ubuntu 11.04, with no special add-ons to Nautilus.

Comment: That trick does not work for me, because on startup `/etc/X11/Xsession` does not check what the symbolic link is pointing to.  For me it creates a new `.xsession-errors` regular file, and has `.xsession-errors.old` linked to `/dev/null`.

That is not what I want.  I want `.xsession-errors` redirected to `/dev/null` - permantently unless I explicitly change it myself.

Comment: Just to clarify @j-johan-edwards.  I tested your command and it works fine, I just want it to be permanent.

Comment: Does 11.04 use GDM or LightDM as its display manager?

Comment: I think mine is GDM, if that is the default.  I have not changed it except to get away from the Unity desktop.

Comment: Yes, my one is GDM.  Apparently the path to `.xsession-errors` is hard coded(?!) into its source code.  Is there a good way to run a script after GDM loads to redirect `.xsession-errors` to `/dev/null`?

Comment: P.S. I downgraded to 10.10 because the TV output would not work.  I am using GDM with 10.10, but the problem is the same.

Comment: Related (if you want to limit its size without completely disabling): http://askubuntu.com/questions/46232/can-i-limit-the-size-of-xsession-errors

Answer (score 10):

I found an interim solution.

I put a small script in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d` called `91redirect-xsession-errors` that does the job for now, but if you want to have your own custom symlink for `.xession-errors` it does not work for that (I tried and it did not output any data).

```
#!/bin/sh

# Redirect $HOME/.xsession-errors to /dev/null.
# BJEM 11 January 2012

XSESSION_ERRFILE=$HOME/.xsession-errors

# This does not seem to work for a regular file,
# i.e. if you want to symlink $HOME/.xsession-errors
# to another file.  I do not know why.
XSESSION_ERRFILE_FINAL=/dev/null

# Creates target file if it does not exist.
touch "$XSESSION_ERRFILE_FINAL"

# Link .xsession-errors file to the desired target
# no matter what.
ln -sf "$XSESSION_ERRFILE_FINAL" "$XSESSION_ERRFILE"

# Test case.
#gedit &

##### END OF FILE #####
```

It's a bit 'rough and ready' but it does the job for me.  Note that this is the *only* file that has been altered.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't notice @earlonrails answer. /etc/X11/Xsession wil create the file in /tmp if it's a symbolic link so this method is useless.

Answer (score 7):

There is a file called /etc/X11/Xsession.
Which will create the symlink to a tmp file.
IE. Starts on line number 61

```
ERRFILE=$HOME/.xsession-errors

# attempt to create an error file; abort if we cannot
if (umask 077 && touch "$ERRFILE") 2> /dev/null && [ -w "$ERRFILE" ] &&
  [ ! -L "$ERRFILE" ]; then
  chmod 600 "$ERRFILE"
elif ERRFILE=$(tempfile 2> /dev/null); then
  if ! ln -sf "$ERRFILE" "${TMPDIR:=/tmp}/xsession-$USER"; then
    message "warning: unable to symlink \"$TMPDIR/xsession-$USER\" to" \
             "\"$ERRFILE\"; look for session log/errors in" \
             "\"$TMPDIR/xsession-$USER\"."
  fi
else
  errormsg "unable to create X session log/error file; aborting."
fi
```

You can cp this Xsession file to Xsession.bak. Then go a head and point your ERRFILE to /dev/null IE. Line 83

```
exec >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Thank you! I wish I'd noticed this answer earlier. I'll award you 200 reputation. I've made a patch that checks for environment variable `$NOXSESSIONERRORS` https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TFxZ344k2p/ this way we can hope to make it upstream.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was a big issue for me years ago when I worked for a company that made kiosks. We would run them from compact flash cards, usually used for cameras. These cards would only have a certain number of writes to them before they would fail write to the cards. Therefore deleting the file many times, as some others suggest, only makes the problem worse.

Comment: I've made a merge request into the [closest thing I could find to upstream](https://askubuntu.com/q/1156256/20275): https://salsa.debian.org/xorg-team/xorg/merge_requests/7 Please add your story about kiosks there.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! However, this seems like a bug in Ubuntu, or rather Debian because I'm encountering it there. Unless I'm missing something, this should have been fixed a long time ago...

Answer (score 3):

In case you still need a solution that keeps logs and has a proper rotation (as it should be for any logged data).

Here is my approach:

replace

```
exec >>"$ERRFILE" 2>&1
```

with

```
exec > >(logger -t xsession-$USER) 2>&1
```

in the `/etc/X11/Xsession` file

That will send all logs to the local syslog server, which can send the logs to the `/var/log/syslog` file by default and have proper logrotate rules

Alternatively, you can route these messages to a separate file, using syslog configuration and have separate logrotate rules for it altogether.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:
execute with sudo

1. `cd` to user folder
2. create new .xsession-errors file e.g.

   echo  test>.xsession-errors
3. `chmod 000 .xsession-errors`
4. Add immutable attribute - even root will not be able write to the file

   chattr +i .xsession-errors

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recover the disk space using [`truncate`](https://superuser.com/questions/609020/how-can-i-create-a-file-with-a-specific-size-from-a-command-line).

If you want to limit the space used for logging, you could do this in a loop or cron. For diagnostic purposes, it might be worthwhile to `tail` the file before truncating.

Optional: Use a hard-link to create a second filename for .xsession-errors in case, for some reason, `truncate` replaces the file without actually truncating the underlying file (this way you won't lose access to the file if it becomes unlinked without being deleted/truncated).

```
mkdir --parents .xsession-errors.backup
tail --lines=10000 .xsession-errors >$(mktemp --tmpdir=. .xsession-errors.backup/XXXXXX)
ln .xsession-errors .xsession-errors.truncate
truncate --size=0 .xsession-errors.truncate
rm --force .xsession-errors.truncate
```

---

Based on the explanation at [What is xsession-errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10222449/86967), these log items are not necessarily system related. It could be some individual application that has gone into a death loop. You can find out which application by looking for the PID at the start of the log lines. Then you probably just want to kill it.

Comment: There's lots of approaches documented in the various 'duplicate' questions.

Comment: The tail-to-backup isn't going to work if the disk is already full.

Answer (score 0):

This issue follows me around on Arch KDE, Neon KDE and now MX KDE. My primary concern here is that the log file is wasting my SSD writes since I like to keep up with long up-times and the issue exacerbates over time. After some days it's going to boost into overdrive and waste my writes.

1. I have put this in my `/etc/fstab` to create a 10MB RAM drive.

```
tmpfs   /media/mkey/tmp tmpfs   size=10000000   0       0
```

2. I have created `a mkey_custom.sh` script in my home directory

```
#!/bin/bash

touch /media/mkey/tmp/.xsession-errors
touch /media/mkey/tmp/.xsession-errors.old

ln -sf /media/mkey/tmp/.xsession-errors /home/mkey/.xsession-errors
ln -sf /media/mkey/tmp/.xsession-errors.old /home/mkey/.xsession-errors.old
```

3. I have created a `mkey_custom.service` file

```
[Unit]
Description=mkey custom service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/mkey/mkey_custom.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

4. Finally, to install and run the service I used the following

```
cp mkey_custom.service /etc/systemd/system/mkey_custom.service
chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/mkey_custom.service
systemctl enable mkey_custom.service
```

I found that I needed to run the script as a service as running it during startup would be too late. The OS would already start writing to the /home location, so any redirects at that point were in vain.

If after a reboot I check the `/home/mkey/.xsession-errors` file properties I will see that it now points to right where I want it `/media/mkey/tmp/.xsession-errors` and that it's being written to.

Answer (score -1):

I faced same problem in redhat linux 6.4 server but i can find which folder or user takes more space by using this command **"find / -xdev -type f -size +100000000c -exec ls -lh {} \;"** then i deleted manually x session errors by using rm -rf command

Comment: This answer does not say HOW to stop the errors. It only says how to delete them. Please update your answer.