# Where is the /etc/X11/Xsession upstream source?

Tags: xorg, source-code

I tried searching [Xorg gitlab](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/) but can't find it for now. I would like to suggest [this patch](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TFxZ344k2p/) to give option of avoiding `.xsession-errors` completely.

Comment: Possible for sending a feature request:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/28440/where-can-i-send-feature-requests

Comment: Thank you for trying, but that question is too broad. I want to make this as a Pull/Merge Request. I hope that this way there are more chances it will not be rejected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's analyze the file origin locally

```
$ dpkg -S  /etc/X11/Xsession
x11-common: /etc/X11/Xsession

$ apt-cache show x11-common | grep Source | sort -u
Source: xorg
```

or using [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=%2Fetc%2FX11%2FXsession) - it says that source package is `xorg`([see this page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/x11-common)).

Semi-appstream is on Debian Salsa - https://salsa.debian.org/xorg-team/xorg/blob/ubuntu/debian/local/Xsession . You can try to send pull request here.

But I can't find this file on Freedesktop Gitlab.

<sub>About the premise - I think that your patch will never be included upstream, because of great possibilities of `.xsession-errors`. Developers and users use this file to determine what is wrong. If you want to change this - change it on your own machine.</sub>

Comment: Thank you, I'll accept it until someone points to a file that's even closer to upstream

Comment: On `.xsession-errors`: I understand that of course, but the patch will not disable it, just create a possibility to opt-in for disabling. Right now there are too many ignored warnings there. I don't agree developers using it to full potential, most of the bugs opened about it are left without reaction.

Answer (score 1):

The source of the Xsession file is Debian.

The file is located in the Debian/Ubuntu xorg source > `debian/local/` folder.

Comment: What makes your answer so unique? :) (comparing with mine [given above](https://askubuntu.com/a/1157233/66509) )

Comment: Only that OP din't see that as upstream, I'm saying Debian, period, not Xorg at all..

Answer (score 0):

[Xorg](https://www.x.org) is the upstream source for the /etc/X11/Xsession file.

If you think that your patch may one or more bugs, check https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/groups/xorg/-/issues to see if those bugs are already being tracked and awaiting your patch.

If you want the patch to get visibility and feedback, try the [xorg-devel mailing list](https://lists.x.org/mailman/listinfo/xorg-devel). However, I suggest starting with the [ubuntu-devel mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-devel), which includes many smart engineers and some Xorg devs - they can give you early feedback if your patch is ready for xorg, or needs some kind of work.

Comment: Thank you, but the question is where exactly on that gitlab is Xsession file?